# how to turnoff org.springframework loggs?

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I have application that when it starts it loading spring context which display messages that I would like to remove like:

```
remote: Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8092
remote: Jul 23, 2014 4:38:56 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
remote: INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1318bd3c: startup date [Wed Jul 23 16:38:56 IDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
remote: Jul 23, 2014 4:38:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
```

I try to add log4j2.xml which looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration name="hook-config" status="warn"
    packages="com.hp">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingFile"
            fileName="logs/preflight.log" filePattern="logs/preflight-%i-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:sss} %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="12" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100" />
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:sss} %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        </logger>
        <Root level="warn">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

didn't help. so I run the application with `-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.diagnostics.dest=STDOUT`
and I got:

```
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Extension directories (java.ext.dir): null
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Application classpath (java.class.path): C:\col\evergreen\git-hook\target\classes;C:\col\evergreen\lt-pcqc\app\Backend\Common\lab-rest-client\target\classes;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.7\junit-4.7.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.3\commons-lang-2.3.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.1\commons-collections-3.1.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-client\2.6\jersey-client-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-common\2.6\jersey-common-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\bundles\repackaged\jersey-guava\2.6\jersey-guava-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-api\2.2.0\hk2-api-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-utils\2.2.0\hk2-utils-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.2.0\aopalliance-repackaged-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\javax.inject\2.2.0\javax.inject-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-locator\2.2.0\hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-json-jackson\2.6\jersey-media-json-jackson-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.9.13\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.9.13\jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\catalina\6.0.26\catalina-6.0.26.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\servlet-api\6.0.26\servlet-api-6.0.26.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\juli\6.0.26\juli-6.0.26.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\annotations-api\6.0.26\annotations-api-6.0.26.jar;C:\col\evergreen\preflight-collector-api\target\classes;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jgit\org.eclipse.jgit\3.0.0.201306101825-r\org.eclipse.jgit-3.0.0.201306101825-r.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\javaewah\JavaEWAH\0.5.6\JavaEWAH-0.5.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\com\jcraft\jsch\0.1.50\jsch-0.1.50.jar;C:\col\evergreen\lt-pcqc\app\Backend\Common\lab-common\target\classes;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\easymock\easymock\3.1\easymock-3.1.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-test-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\jboss\cache\jbosscache-core\3.2.5.GA\jbosscache-core-3.2.5.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\jgroups\jgroups\2.6.13.GA\jgroups-2.6.13.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\jboss\javaee\jboss-transaction-api\1.0.1.GA\jboss-transaction-api-1.0.1.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jboss-common-core\2.2.14.GA\jboss-common-core-2.2.14.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging-spi\2.0.5.GA\jboss-logging-spi-2.0.5.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory was loaded via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Ancestry of classloader which loaded org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 == 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7d16ecf'
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Ancestry of classloader which loaded org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory is ClassLoader tree:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 (SYSTEM)  --> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@1187109899 --> BOOT
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] BOOTSTRAP COMPLETED
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] LogFactory implementation requested for the first time for context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 == 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7d16ecf'
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] ClassLoader tree:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 (SYSTEM)  --> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@1187109899 --> BOOT
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] No properties file of name 'commons-logging.properties' found.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] Looking for system property [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] to define the LogFactory subclass to use...
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] No system property [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] defined.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] Looking for a resource file of name [META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] to define the LogFactory subclass to use...
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] No resource file with name 'META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory' found.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] No properties file available to determine LogFactory subclass from..
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] Loading the default LogFactory implementation 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' via the same classloader that loaded this LogFactory class (ie not looking in the context classloader).
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Loaded class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl from classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Instance created.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Created object org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl@6199956 to manage classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Discovering a Log implementation...
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Trying to get configuration for item org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedContext
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No LogFactory attribute found for org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedContext
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No system property found for property org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedContext
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No configuration defined for item org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedContext
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Trying to get configuration for item org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedDiscovery
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No LogFactory attribute found for org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedDiscovery
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No system property found for property org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedDiscovery
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No configuration defined for item org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedDiscovery
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Trying to get configuration for item org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedHierarchy
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No LogFactory attribute found for org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedHierarchy
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No system property found for property org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedHierarchy
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] No configuration defined for item org.apache.commons.logging.Log.allowFlawedHierarchy
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Trying to get log class from attribute 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log'
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Trying to get log class from attribute 'org.apache.commons.logging.log'
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Trying to get log class from system property 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log'
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Trying to get log class from system property 'org.apache.commons.logging.log'
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] No user-specified Log implementation; performing discovery using the standard supported logging implementations...
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Attempting to instantiate 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger'
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Trying to load 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' from classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' was found at 'jar:file:/C:/Users/sunino/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar!/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.class'
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] The log adapter 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' is missing dependencies when loaded via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903: org/apache/log4j/Category
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Attempting to instantiate 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger'
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Trying to load 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger' from classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger' was found at 'jar:file:/C:/Users/sunino/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar!/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Jdk14Logger.class'
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [INFO] 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger' from classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 does not declare optional method setLogFactory(LogFactory)
[LogFactoryImpl@6199956 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Log adapter 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger' from classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 has been selected for use.
```

so, although I mark the level as warn or error, still INFO messages shows up.
what am I missing?

I added the log4j-jcl jar a s suggested in [jcl-bridge](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jcl/index.html)
and got the following execption:

```
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Extension directories (java.ext.dir): null
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Application classpath (java.class.path): C:\col\evergreen\git-hook\target\classes;C:\col\evergreen\lt-pcqc\app\Backend\Common\lab-rest-client\target\classes;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.7\junit-4.7.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.3\commons-lang-2.3.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.1\commons-collections-3.1.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-client\2.6\jersey-client-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-common\2.6\jersey-common-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\bundles\repackaged\jersey-guava\2.6\jersey-guava-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-api\2.2.0\hk2-api-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-utils\2.2.0\hk2-utils-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.2.0\aopalliance-repackaged-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\javax.inject\2.2.0\javax.inject-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-locator\2.2.0\hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-json-jackson\2.6\jersey-media-json-jackson-2.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.9.13\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.9.13\jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\catalina\6.0.26\catalina-6.0.26.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\servlet-api\6.0.26\servlet-api-6.0.26.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\juli\6.0.26\juli-6.0.26.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\annotations-api\6.0.26\annotations-api-6.0.26.jar;C:\col\evergreen\preflight-collector-api\target\classes;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jgit\org.eclipse.jgit\3.0.0.201306101825-r\org.eclipse.jgit-3.0.0.201306101825-r.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\javaewah\JavaEWAH\0.5.6\JavaEWAH-0.5.6.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\com\jcraft\jsch\0.1.50\jsch-0.1.50.jar;C:\col\evergreen\lt-pcqc\app\Backend\Common\lab-common\target\classes;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\easymock\easymock\3.1\easymock-3.1.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.2\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-test-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.2.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\jboss\cache\jbosscache-core\3.2.5.GA\jbosscache-core-3.2.5.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\jgroups\jgroups\2.6.13.GA\jgroups-2.6.13.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\jboss\javaee\jboss-transaction-api\1.0.1.GA\jboss-transaction-api-1.0.1.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jboss-common-core\2.2.14.GA\jboss-common-core-2.2.14.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging-spi\2.0.5.GA\jboss-logging-spi-2.0.5.GA.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-jcl\2.0\log4j-jcl-2.0.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sunino\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0\log4j-api-2.0.jar
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory was loaded via classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Ancestry of classloader which loaded org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 == 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7d16ecf'
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [ENV] Ancestry of classloader which loaded org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory is ClassLoader tree:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 (SYSTEM)  --> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@1187109899 --> BOOT
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] BOOTSTRAP COMPLETED
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] LogFactory implementation requested for the first time for context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 == 'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7d16ecf'
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] ClassLoader tree:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903 (SYSTEM)  --> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@1187109899 --> BOOT
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] No properties file of name 'commons-logging.properties' found.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] Looking for system property [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] to define the LogFactory subclass to use...
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] No system property [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] defined.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP] Looking for a resource file of name [META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory] to define the LogFactory subclass to use...
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] [LOOKUP]  Creating an instance of LogFactory class org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl as specified by file 'META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory' which was present in the path of the context classloader.
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Loaded class org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl from classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
[LogFactory from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903] Created object org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl@1296806005 to manage classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@131165903
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext;
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:268)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl$PrivateManager.getContext(LogFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getLoggersMap(LogFactoryImpl.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader.<clinit>(AbstractContextLoader.java:64)
```

Comment: AFAIK Commons logging doesn't support LOG4j2 . The logger used is the default `java.util.Logging`. Your Log4j2 is completly ignored. To have log4j2 work with commons logging you need the [commons logging bridge](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jcl/).

Comment: can you suggest how to fix the xml file?

Comment: Have you read my comment? You cannot fix the xml file the problem lies in the fact you are using commons logging. The link I provided gives you the solution.

Comment: I added the jcl-bridge as suggested and edit the Q with the exception

Comment: Make sure that you use compatible jar versions.

Comment: you are right, I used log4j-jcl version 2.0 which is new from July 14 which use common logging version 1.2 while my spring core use common loggin version 1.1.1.
so I change the the version of log4j-jcl to be 2.0-beta8 and it solved the conflict.
10x!

Comment: Do you have log4j-core as well?

Comment: yea I do have log4j-core